# PHP catalog, click on item image to display product details

Tags: php

I am trying to build a simple catalog displaying items from a mysql database.
So far I can get the items to display in a list format including the images stored as a path in the items table in a field called "path".

I would like the ability to be able to click on the item image and it takes you to a dedicated page showing you the details of that product. The link would correspond to which ever item you click on based on the data in the item table.

So far I have the following code;

```
 <?php
session_start();
require "connect.php";
$date = date("d-M-Y");
$query =  "select * from item order by date && time asc limit 0,3";
$query2 = "select * from users where userid = ".$_SESSION['userid'];
$result = @mysql_query($query, $connection) 
or die ("Unable to perform query<br>$query");
 ?>

 <?php
  while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  ?>
 <?php echo $row['item'] ?>
 <?php echo $row['description'] ?>
 //Code for Image Link
 <a href='<a href='<?php echo $row['path']?>'><img src="<?php echo $row['path']?>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

The above code allows you to click on the image and it takes me to http://127.0.0.1/steal/%3Ca%20href=

However I don't know what I would need to enter in order for it to take me to a page that shows the product? 
Please Help

Many Thanks

Comment: I would suggest closing your html tags `</a>` at the appropriate places, due to your while, you might create overlapping links, and cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another page called for example `showProductsOrder.php` that accepts the orderID and then does output the content.

```
showProductsOrder.php?orderID=1
<?php
      SELECT * FROM order WHERE orderID = $_GET['orderID']  
      while(fetch()) {
         //> Show product here
      }
?>
```

Also please don't use mysql_query. Use `php.net/pdo`

### Addendum

```
<a href="showProductsOrder?orderID=<?php echo $row['id']?>">Show all products</a>
```

Comment: OK Thanks how do I apply the link to showProductsOrder.php from the line of code - <a href='<a href='<?php echo $row['path']?>'><img src="<?php echo $row['path']?>"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your database schema, so I'm taking some liberties here about your columns for the product. But, try this:

`<a href="/product_page.php?product_id?<?php echo $row['id']?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['path']?"/></a>`

I also am not sure what your product page URL is either, so change `product_page.php` to whatever template you are using to display your products.

Answer (score 0):

As yes123 said you would need to create another page, but i if you have a problem creating the link here is my suggested solution:
Replace your link with:

```
<?php echo ("<a href='".$row['pagePath']."'><img src='".$row['imagePath']."' /></a>";?>
```

$row['pagePath'] is the page that it will load when the image is clicked on, and
$row['imagePath'] is where the image is stored on your pc / server.